# Error de DLL, Aplicación de PyQt6 con pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, pyqt6

Estoy creando una aplicación de PyQt6, y estoy usando Pyinstaller para crear mi aplicación.

Al ejecutar el ejecutable desde mi computadora funciona correctamente, pero al intentar ejecutarlo en otra computadora sin Python me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: The specified module could not be found.
[26092] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

mi versión de PyQt6 es 6.6.1

mi versión de Pyinstaller es 6.3.0

Mi pregunta es:

- ¿a que dll hace referencia el error?
- ¿Se puede ejecutar un programa creado de pyinstaller en una computadora sin Python?
- ¿Cómo añado la dll faltante?

Comment: 1- ¿PyInstaller no agrega los DLL en la carpeta de salida?, 2- Claro, pero debes incluir los DLL usados en la misma carpeta de tu app.